# looping the array of json object in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am new in reactjs. I have problem while showing the result.Here is my code:

```
constructor (props) {
      super(props);
       this.state = {
         selectValue: '',
         yearsValue:'',
         months:''
       }
     this.setDataGroup = this.setDataGroup.bind(this);
   }

setDataGroup(e){
    var selectedType = e.target.value;
    if(selectedType == "quertly"){
       var quertlyData = [{
        data:"Jan-March",
        value:"1"
      },
      {
        data:"Apr-Jun",
        value:"2"
      },
      {
        data:"Jul-Sept",
        value:"3"
      },
      {
        data:"Oct-Dec",
        value:"4"
      }];
       this.setState({yearsValue:quertlyData});
```

I am showing the data like:

```
 render() {
 const data = JSON.stringify(this.state.yearsValue) || []
                  <div>
    {data.map((data, index) => {data})}
  </div>
}
```

My json looks like:

[{"data":"Jan-March","value":"1"},{"data":"Apr-Jun","value":"2"},{"data":"Jul-Sept","value":"3"},{"data":"Oct-Dec","value":"4"}]

Getting error .map is not function

Comment: why stringify? the data is an array already and I am assuming you don't want to get it as a string. Also your render method is mute, what do you expect from the mapping function, since the arrow function will return undefined for all elements

Comment: `yearsValue` is a `string`. `JSON.stringify` won't turn it into an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yearsValue` is a string and therefore using `JSON.stringify` won't help you.

Also, `render` method **must** return something:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    selectValue: '',
    yearsValue: [],
    months:''
  }

  this.setDataGroup = this.setDataGroup.bind(this);
}
... 
render() {
  const { yearsValue } = this.state

  return (
    <div>
      {yearsValue.map((item, index) =>
        <div key={index}>{item.data}:{item.value}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: `yearsValue` is an array, if it would be a string `JSON.parse` would be helpful

Comment: So it's better to user proper types than trying to `parse` on every render. Performance-wise this is a bad patern.

Comment: Yeah, I believe the OPs confusion is surrounding his constructor setup, and the `setState` method inside his `setDataGroup` function

Comment: Agree. That's why I suggested to initialize `yearsValue` as an array in the constructor.

Comment: @Karan did you change it in the constructor as well? It has to be an array, otherwise it will always break.

Answer (score 2):

Your data is in correct format. Initialize `yearsValue` as array in `constructor` like

```
this.state = {
  yearsValue: []
}
```

And then you can use `yearsValue` state in `render` like below

```
render() {
  return (
     <div>
       {this.state.yearsValue.map((d, index) => {
          return (
             <div key={index}>{d.data}</div>
          )
       })}
     </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Presumably `yearsValue` could be an empty string, which wouldn't have `map`

Comment: @Icepickle - Yes correct. I have updated the answer..Hope that might work.

Comment: Well, almost, the render method doesn't return anything yet ;)

Comment: You are close. Just missed the return from `render`

Comment: Thanks @mersocarlin